# CMake workflow of adding a library which uses CMake

Tags: cmake

```
#include "somelib/some.h"

int main(){}
```

I have a 3rd party library that has a pretty messy structure but it uses CMake. How would I add that library to my project so that I could just use it as I have written above?

Do I have to manually build and move every file by myself or is there a shortcut?

something like

```
mkdir lib
mv path/somelib lib
```

and in my CMakeLists.txt I could just add something like

```
ADD_CMAKE_LIB(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/somelib)
```

And everything would magically work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following options:

1. Build 3rd party lib out of your project, install it anywhere and write your own, for example, FindMessyLib.cmake within your project to search for specific header and libs
2. Add <project root>/ext/yourmessylib under your source control and use [add_subdirectory](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_subdirectory)(ext/yourmessylib) in your top-level CMakeLists.txt project file
3. Use [ExternalProject_Add](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module:ExternalProject). Example can be found [here](https://github.com/snikulov/google-test-examples).

Personally, I prefer second approach combined with **git submodule**. If git is not used - I'll vote for third.

Comment: `I prefer second approach combined with git submodule` good luck with boost :)